# Parse multiple json in one line in pyspark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a json line as follows:

```
{"test":"valid2","workflowId":79370,"email":"d1@example.com"}{"email":"d1@example.com","eventName":"emailOpen","dataFields":{"campaignId":1125010,"ip":"100.100.200.243","userAgentDevice":"Gmail","messageId":"be4e071c11594bb0b4ee3c444fd08b99","emailId":"d1@example.com","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko Firefox/11.0 (via ggpht.com GoogleImageProxy)","workflowName":"DWH TEST 06042020 WITH CALL","locale":null,"templateId":1576122,"emailSubject":"DWH TEST","labels":[],"createdAt":"2020-04-06 15:06:16 +00:00","templateName":"DWH TEST","messageTypeId":27043,"experimentId":79413,"campaignName":"DWH Test Automation","workflowId":79370,"email":"d1@example.com","channelId":24365}}{"email":"dd1@example.com","eventName":"emailOpen","dataFields":{"campaignId":1100,"ip":"50.100.200.243","userAgentDevice":"Gmail","messageId":"zz4e071c11594bb0b4ee3c444fd08b99","emailId":"dd1@example.com","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko Firefox/11.0 (via ggpht.com GoogleImageProxy)","workflowName":"TEST","locale":null,"templateId":1576122,"emailSubject":"TEST","labels":"Cambbridge test","createdAt":"2020-04-10 15:06:16 +00:00","templateName":"TEST","messageTypeId":27043,"experimentId":89413,"campaignName":"Cambridge Test","workflowId":18370,"email":"dd1@example.com","channelId":1111}}{"email":"dd1@example.com","eventName":"emailClick","dataFields":{"campaignId":1100,"ip":"50.100.200.243","userAgentDevice":"Gmail","messageId":"zzee071c11594bb0b4ee3c444fd08b99","emailId":"dd1@example.com","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko Firefox/11.0 (via ggpht.com GoogleImageProxy)","workflowName":"TEST","locale":null,"templateId":1576122,"emailSubject":"TEST","labels":"Cambbridge test","createdAt":"2020-04-10 15:08:16 +00:00","templateName":"TEST","messageTypeId":27043,"experimentId":89413,"campaignName":"Cambridge Test","workflowId":18370,"email":"dd1@example.com","channelId":1111}}{"test":"valid2","workflowId":79370,"email":"d1@example.com"}{"email":"d1@example.com","eventName":"emailOpen","dataFields":{"campaignId":1125010,"ip":"100.100.200.243","userAgentDevice":"Gmail","messageId":"be4e071c11594bb0b4ee3c444fd08b99","emailId":"d1@example.com","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko Firefox/11.0 (via ggpht.com GoogleImageProxy)","workflowName":"DWH TEST 06042020 WITH CALL","locale":null,"templateId":1576122,"emailSubject":"DWH TEST","labels":[],"createdAt":"2020-04-06 15:06:16 +00:00","templateName":"DWH TEST","messageTypeId":27043,"experimentId":79413,"campaignName":"DWH Test Automation","workflowId":79370,"email":"d1@example.com","channelId":24365}}
```

As you can see there are multiple jsons in one single line.
I need to associate the extra json json object "{"test":"valid2","workflowId":79370,"email":"d1@example.com"}", with all/any event jsons followed by it as long as workflowId and email of the extra json match with the event's workflowId and email.

There can multiple such extra jsons followed by events in one single.
I dont know how to ready such a file using a combination of python and pyspark.
Using pyspark is mandatory.
I tried:

```
df = sql_context.read.json('test.json')
df.show()
```

but the output is just the extra json :

```
+--------------+------+----------+
|         email|  test|workflowId|
+--------------+------+----------+
|c1@example.com|valid1|     79370|
+--------------+------+----------+
```

I would want the output to look like:

```
        id                              email           event     workflow_id   custom  createdatdate   createdattime
0   be4e071c11594bb0b4ee3c444fd08b99    d1@example.com  emailOpen   79370       valid2  2020414         154248
1   be4e071c11594bb0b4ee3c444fd08b99    d1@example.com  emailOpen   79370       valid2  2020414         154248
```

Can anyone guide me on how to process such a file and get resultant df using pyspark

Comment: That's not legitimate JSON.  If you can assume every JSON document is a single object, you could replace `}{` with `}\n{` and then use `.splitlines()`.

Answer (score 3):

Because this is malformed JSON, I would recommend that you run a pre-processing step that repairs the file. This can be done easily with the `jq` command-line utility. See [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

The `-c` flag is for compact output, and will result in newline-delimited JSON instead of it being pretty-printed.

```sh
jq -c . test.json > test_repaired.json
```

You can then read in that file with Spark like so:

```py
>>> spark \
...     .read \
...     .json('test_repaired.json') \
...     .show()
+--------------------+---------------+----------+------+----------+
|          dataFields|          email| eventName|  test|workflowId|
+--------------------+---------------+----------+------+----------+
|                null| d1@example.com|      null|valid2|     79370|
|{1125010, DWH Tes...| d1@example.com| emailOpen|  null|      null|
|{1100, Cambridge ...|dd1@example.com| emailOpen|  null|      null|
|{1100, Cambridge ...|dd1@example.com|emailClick|  null|      null|
|                null| d1@example.com|      null|valid2|     79370|
|{1125010, DWH Tes...| d1@example.com| emailOpen|  null|      null|
+--------------------+---------------+----------+------+----------+
```

Comment: This is great to read the json in a dataframe. But I dont have to have a line row for that extra json. I need to map it with the events followed based on email and worflowid.
So ideally there should be only rows in the df for which the email and workflow id in extra json match with the event.
dataFields|                   email|                     eventName|  test|   workflowId|
+--------------------+---------------+----------+------+----------+
|{1125010, DWH Tes...| d1@example.com| emailOpen|  valid2|      79370|
|{1125010, DWH Tes...| d1@example.com| emailOpen|  valid2|      79370|

Comment: I see. In that case you could programmatically repair the JSON and discard the unneeded data. Or you could read it all into the Dataframe, and then use a `df.where` clause to remove entries where `email` is null.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to repair jsons in python

Comment: Tim Roberts' recommendation of replacing the "}{" characters with a newline-delimiter is useful for that, or alternatively you can create a JSON array: `j: str = "[" + my_json.replace("}{", "},{") + "]"`, which can then be deserialized with `json.loads(j)`. You can then filter out items that don't have the attributes you need. But if your data is large, I recommend trying to do as much as you can in Spark.